# How to make a picture fit on the page with navigation

Tags: html, css, image, navigation

So what I'm trying to do is make my image fit on the page without having a scroll. It's obvious that the jumbotron and nav are pushing the image down, so what makes sense to me, is to put the image behind the jumbotron and nav. I tried an overflow of hidden, and that didn't seem to work. I also tried putting everything inside my wrapper, that worked, but then my responsive design got all messed up. This is the picture here that would cover the page: [https://static.pexels.com/photos/7106/macbook-computer-clean-hero.jpg][1].

Here is my code:

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.jumbotron {
background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
padding-bottom: 0;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-top: 20px;
h1 {
font-size: 5em;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 100;
color: #fff;
margin: .2em 0 0 .2em;
letter-spacing: .2em;
span {
font-weight: normal;
}
}
p {
color: #fff;
margin-right: .5em;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
#slogan {
font-size: 1.2em;
margin: 0;
margin-right: 20px;
}
}
.navbar {
background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
border-radius: 0;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
min-height: 0;
border: none;
li a {
outline: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 5px 15px 10px 15px;
font-size: .9em;
}
}
.wrapper{ // The wrapper is ONLY on the index.html page.
// position: relative;
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
color: #FFF;
background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/7106/macbook-computer-clean-hero.jpg");
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
}
.h2_slogan {
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 3em;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header class="jumbotron">
   <h1>John <span>Smith</span></h1>
   <p class="text-right" id="slogan">Accessible. Affordable. Dependable.</p>
</header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
<div class="wrapper">
   <h2 class="text-center h2_slogan">Web Developer & Designer</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to put the image as background for `body`? or reduce the `height` of the image?

Comment: @MaihanNijat Yes, but I only want it on my home page. If I put it on the body, it'll appear on all my other pages.

Comment: It will not appear on all your other pages if you put it as background in the body.

Comment: @MaihanNijat Are you talking about HTML or CSS? If I put it on my CSS, it will in fact appear on all my other pages. Hence why I have a class of "wrapper" on my index page and "container" on my other pages. I don't want the image to appear on the index (home page). Having it on the body will be universal with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add it to your `body` this will put it behind both the `jumbotron` and the `navbar`.

What you do:

Change this in your **HTML**

From:

```
<body>
```

To:

```
<body id="homepage">
```

---

Add this to your **CSS**:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../img/header.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

And that's basically it.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ges3sv3w/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That would work, but I don't want the image to appear on the other pages. I should have been more specific on the post. But I just want it to appear on the index.html (home) page.

Comment: @J.Bon use inline style for body or define class or id for the body.

Comment: @MaihanNijat Thank you! I wasn't too sure if that's against proper code or not.

Comment: @Simplicity Thank you! I wasn't too sure if making an ID or CLASS was proper code but this will work! Thank you.

Comment: @J.Bon Don't thank me alone since I'm not the only one who said this, but  still, no problem at all!